# If statements for multiple lines of input using dictionaries

Tags: python

Im having a bit of trouble with this python problem, so the first part of the task is to basically read from multiple lines of input until a blank line is entered.

If the first word is 'Capture', there will be two words following it: the name of the Pokémon (e.g. Pikachu) and its current level (e.g. 5) so it would look something like this: "Capture Pikachu 5"

If the first word is Query, the next word will be the name of a Pokémon. Your program should print the level of the Pokémon that you have previously captured, or it should warn the user if it is not tracking that Pokémon name. For example, if I typed "Capture Pikachu 5" previously, and then wrote "Query Pikachu" in the next line of input, it would return "Pikachu is level 5." If I wrote "Query Eevee" instead of "Query Pikachu", it would instead say "You have not captured Eevee yet".

If I try to "Capture" a Pokémon that has already been captured, (e.g. I write "Capture Pikachu 5" then in the next line I write "Capture Pikachu 4") it will say "You are already training Pikachu!"

Finally, if I enter any unknown command apart from "Capture" and "Query", then it will say "Unknown Command!"

Heres my code so far:

```
while line:
  if 'Capture' in line:   
    parts = line.split()
    name = parts[1]
    number = parts[2]
    line = input('Command: ')
  elif 'Query' in line and parts[1] in line:
    print(name, 'is level', number + '.')
    line = input('Command: ')
  elif 'Capture' in line and parts[1] == name:
    part3 = line.split()
    notname2 = part3[1]
    print('You are already training', notname2 + '!')
    line = input('Command: ')
  elif 'Query' in line and parts[1] not in line:
    part2 = line.split()
    notname = part2[1]
    print('You have not captured', notname, 'yet.')
    line = input('Command: ')
  else:
    print('Unknown command!')
    line = input('Command: ')
```

Everything seems to work except for when you try to capture a Pokémon that has already been captured. For example, if I wrote "Capture Eevee 3" then wrote "Capture Eevee 5", I want it to say "You are already training Eevee!" but instead it does not say anything and just asks for the next line of input.

I have not used the dictionary function in my code but managed to get it work otherwise, but I probably have to use it at some point, I just don't know how to implement it.

I'm not exactly sure what the problem in my code is, as everything else seems to work perfectly fine, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: I noticed that `parts = line.split()` is only present in the very first `if` clause, so if 'Capture' is _not_ in the line, the next `elif 'Query' ...` statement will use the `parts` that was defined in the previous line. Since you know you're going to want to look the individual words in every line, consider moving `parts = line.split()` up to right after the `while line` statement. Same goes for `line = input('Command: ')`: since you're doing that every time through the loop, put it at the top of the loop (perhaps followed by `if not line: continue` so that empty lines aren't processed).

Answer (score 2):

Don't program directly into a cold page: design your logic flow in some sort of diagram that works for you (e.g. flowchart), and code from that.  THe code you wrote will *not* reach the clause that recognizes a previous Pokemon, because you have a containing condition in your first clause.  Any `Capture` will go through the first `if` block, regardless of what else is on the input line.

Try making a decision tree instead: *inside* your `if "Capture" ...` block, immediately check whether you have that Pokemon yet:

```
if "Capture" in line:
    parts = line.split()
    name = parts[1]
    if name ...     # if the name is already seen, print error message
```

You'll need to do likewise with your "Query" checks.

Note that I haven't *repaired* your "re-capture" line, because you haven't properly tracked the Pokemon characters you've already captured.  If your posted code *were* to get through to the lower branches, it would fail or work incorrectly because you haven't properly defined `parts` and `name` for those other branches.

---

Stop trying to code the entire program at once; you've made enough errors that you'll have to fix several at once to get the expected output.  Instead, code a simple `if` statement first; make sure that works (can differentiate between commands, for instance) before you add any more logic.  *Then* add something that recognizes a re-capture.

Answer (score 2):

yes it will be easier if you use dict for example

```
Pokedex={} #or bag ={}
```

in your actual code you cant know which pokemon did you catch, if you use a dict like {pokemon:lvl}
example

```
Pokedex["Eevee"]=3
```

so you can check if that Eevee exist with a code like:

```
if pokename in Pokedex.keys(): 
    print("you have a " + pokename + "in your bag") 
else: 
    print("Adding a "+pokename+ " in your pokedex")
    Pokedex[pokename]=pokelvl
```

Comment: You'd always want to write that `if` statement like `if pokename in Pokedex` (minus the `.keys()` part).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote you this, should work perfectly

```
done = False
owned_poks = []
poks_levels = []
while not done:
    line = input('Command: ')
    if line:
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[0] == 'Capture' and not parts[1] in owned_poks:
            owned_poks.append(parts[1])
            poks_levels.append(parts[2])
            print('Captured!')
        elif parts[0] == 'Query' and parts[1] in owned_poks:
            print('{} is level {}'.format(parts[1], poks_levels[owned_poks.index(parts[1])]))
        elif parts[0] == 'Capture' and parts[1] in owned_poks:
            print('You already have this pokemon')
        elif parts[0] == 'Query' and not parts[1] in owned_poks:
            print('you dont have this poke')
        else:
            print('Unkown command')
    else:
        done = True
```

Comment: this `poks_levels[owned_poks.index(parts[1])]` won't work properly if there are several pokemons in the list with the same name -- you'll always find the first one.

Comment: There can't be several pokemons with the same name because once you've captured a pokemon it's gonna be unique since when you query another Capture the program will tell you that such a pokemon is already in the list. However i didn't think of that so i give you props for finding the potential bug!